# Prevent Access to Local Storage via Developer Tools?

Tags: javascript, html, security, google-chrome, web

I know there has been a lot of discussion on the [evils](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/03/there-is-no-simple-solution-for-local-storage/) vs. the [good](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/03/07/in-defense-of-localstorage/) of local storage. There have also been Chrome [hacks](http://davidwalsh.name/disable-console) for disabling a user's/visitor's ability to run JavaScript from the console *which have had limited success*.

None of these have addressed my question: **can you prevent a user from editing local storage values in their browser?**

This will never be the ideal or permanent solution to a current issue, I just need a way to do this until we can refactor the codebase to use [IndexedDB](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/).

**EDIT**: There is no sensitive data being handled in local storage for this app which is only available to local users on an in-house network. There are some data points that a handful of users have learned can be edited and it is these users the project owner is concerned about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. Even if there is a temporary 'solution' or hack that seems to work, it is still the web, so there is no way to prevent access to it. Trying to prevent a user from accessing a resource on their own system is doomed to fail.

Methods I can think of inside *and* outside the browser to read from and write to the local storage:

- Inject JavaScript in the page to read the local storage;
- Create your own browser or browser plug-in;
- Read the SQLite databases in `%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this. There is no way to control a user's browser in this way, and there *should never be*. That is antithetical to the nature of the Internet. Your server publishes code. People consume that code using *some kind of browser*. That's it. You have no control over what reads your code or what it *does* with the code once you've served it up.

Your approach to security is completely wrong. You cannot secure this on the client's side.

It's up to you to use localStorage securely from the get-go. That means you **cannot** trust any data stored there, and you cannot store anything there that you don't want the user to read. There, or in cookies, or in IndexedDB, or in *any* client-side data store. Security comes from inherently mistrusting any user-submitted data. You need to validate any and all data that a user sends to your server, full stop. Trying to prevent them from changing the data cannot work, because they can just *write their own data*. They can produce a request that will send literally *anything* to your server.

If you're storing sensitive data in localStorage or any other client-side data storage, you're doing it completely wrong, and you need to abandon that approach, because it cannot be salvaged.